# Find-based mv renaming fails in a shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find, mv

I wanted to do a simple script to rename files, well parts of files. While the command works just fine from commandline:

```
find . -type f -name "*old*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/old/new}"' {} \; 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied" | grep -v "are the same file"
```

I tried to reimplement it in a shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
# renamefiles.sh - type renamefiles <old> <new>
# 
find . -type f -name "*$1*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/$1/$2}"' {} \; 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied" | grep -v "are the same file"
```

When user would type,

```
$ renamefiles old new
```

A failure would occur (with error message suppressing disabled):

```
mv: './File0_old.txt' and './File0_new.txt' are the same file
mv: './Another_old_file.txt' and './Another_new_file.txt' are the same file
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with two possible solutions first, then describe why you got the error.

**Solution 1::**

Just "temporarily" export the two variables so that they will be available to your sub-shell

```
#!/bin/bash
# renamefiles.sh - type renamefiles <old> <new>

export from="$1" && export to="$2" && find . -type f -name "*$1*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/$from/$to}"' "{}" \; 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"


exit 0
```

So here we export $1 into variable from, and $2 into variable to. This way, the sub-shell will be able to read them.

**Solution 2::** (simpler, and may be preferred by those who don't like the temporary export thingie)

```
#!/bin/bash
# renamefiles.sh - type renamefiles <old> <new>

find . -type f -name "*$1*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/$1/$2}"' "{}" "$1" "$2" \; 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"

exit 0
```

This solution consists of just passing "$1" and "$2" besides {} (the current result from find) so that the sub-shell can access them normally as if it was a script on its own (with the exception that with the -c option passed to bash, the first argument would be $0 instead of $1; this seems to be known by you, as you've already used it)

**Common notices regarding the two solutions::**

1. Always include an exit command at the end of your scripts
2. Note the quoting for every variable being passed, even for {}. This would prevent misinterpretation for variables with spaces. Do this even if you're sure you don't have values or [here] filenames with spaces, as you don't know when you'll be later using your script.

**Reason behind the error::**

The reason behind the error you got ("are the same file") is very simple.

In your script, the mv command replaced the given file "$0" with another file given by the result of a string substitution ("${0/$1/$2}"). So in your case, $1 and $2 were not given to the sub-shell command, so it's like you did "${0//}" which would do nothing. As a result, the old and new filenames would be the same, hence the error.